# iframe content access in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

In my application im using the below code for creating a pop up and inserting an iframe to it.

```
     var win = window.open("", "", "height=200,width=150")        

    var newFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    newFrame.setAttribute("src", "newpage.html");
    newFrame.setAttribute("name", "fr1");        

    win.document.body.appendChild(newFrame);

**var ifrm = win.document.getElementById('fr1');
ifrmdocument = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;**
```

I can add an iframe but unable to access the iframe document. My requirement is i need to modify the iframe content dynamically. the highlighted lines shows error.

Also while accessing  win.document.getElementById('fr1') i'm getting error.
Please share your thoughts.

Comment: I think you want `contentWindow.document`, not `contentDocument`

Comment: You cannot access a page from another domain

Comment: @pedalpete i cant access the iframe element.

Comment: @mplungjan even i'm getting error after changed to a page in the same domain.

Comment: Try win=window.open("samedomainpage.html","winname","....") - I am not sure the new window has the same origin as the page it was opened from. Anyway why a new window and why an iFrame. Why not a lightbox-type modal div?